Proper connections between Heat Pump Water Heater and mixing valve
I'm planning to install a Rheem Hybrid Heat Pump water heater, and want to include a thermostatic mixing valve. Rheem suggests a flexible connection between the water heater and the plumbing to avoid introducing vibration noise into the plumbing system. I would prefer to use corrugated copper or corrugated stainless steel hoses instead of PEX. The water heater connector hoses are FIP (with a washer in the connector), the shutoff valves and mixing valve are NPT. I'm planning to sweat most connections but plan to use threaded connections on the valves so there is no risk of overheating during the sweating.
See diagram below with all the parts I plan to use (not to scale). Do you see any issues with this combination of components? Anything you would do differently?
I have ordered the Apollo shutoff valves and have the water heater, and am about to order the other parts.
Thanks

What?! Not to scale? Where's the downvote button... Ha ha, no, really, very nice diagram and easy to understand. Looks like a reasonable setup to me, but I'm no plumber. +1.
